# How to make a resumable upload for attachments through Gmail API in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, gmail-api

Please do not share the documentation link, it's not straight forward and also the uploading using RNFS and document-picker is a bit confusing..

Code:

```
const uploadAttachments = async (data, sessionURI, message, onProgress) => {
  const {files} = message;
  let length = 0;
  const formatedFileData = files.map(item => {
    length += item.size;
    return {
      name: item.filename,
      filename: item.filename,
      filepath: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + item.filename,
      filetype: item.filetype,
    };
  });
  RNFS.uploadFiles({
    toUrl: sessionURI,
    files: formatedFileData,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + (await getUserToken()),
      'Content-Length': length.toString(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    fields: data,
    progress: onProgress,
  })
    .promise.then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
const requestSession = async (data: any, postUrl: string) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios({
      data: data,
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + (await getUserToken()),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'message/rfc822',
      },
      method: 'post',
      url: postUrl,
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
export const resumeableUpload = async (message, onProgress) => {
  try {
    const data = await getMetaData(message);
    const response = await requestSession(data, RESUMABLE_URL);
    const sessionURI = response.headers.location;
    const res = await uploadAttachments(data, sessionURI, message, onProgress);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I get the error from RNFS saying the 'Socket is closed'!
May be the way i'm uploading the file itself is wrong or is there any other way to upload files to the session uri?
If I send base64encoded bytes of the file, it raw feild becomes too huge for files over 5MB (25mb files) and the app crashes

Comment: Have you tried something? if yes, share the code.

Comment: Hey i've updated with my code @pai.not.pi